# Load XML and apply variables

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, variables

Could someone have a look at my as3-code and tell me what is wrong with it? An XML file should be loaded and its content should be assigned to variables, which are accessible over the whole flash-document.

AS3-Code:

```
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.net.*;

var XML_URL:String = "text.xml"; //Name of the XML-File
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL);
myLoader.addEventListener("complete", xmlLoaded);

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    myXML = XML(myLoader.data);
    fnXML(myXML);
    trace("XML LOADED!")
}

function fnXML(main:XML):void
{
    //Here are the variables that should be accessible through the whole flash-document.
    var e01_h:String = main.experimente.task.text();
    var e01_t:String = main.experimente.exp01.header.text();

}
```

It's impossible to add some XML-Code here. I can not upload pictures and the format from copy and paste looks terrible. But I am pretty sure that the called path is correct.

Comment: OK So what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

These vars defined inside `fnXML` function. There is no way they could be accessible through entire document. They are function execution-time variables which will be deallocated after function complete it work.
You should define variable outside of function definition.

```
var e01_h:String;
var e01_t:String;
//etc
```

And then give them values inside your function

```
function fnXML(main:XML):void
{
   e01_h = main.experimente.e01.head.text();
   e01_t = main.experimente.e01.txt.text();
}
```

Access to created varibles from the everywhere of you project is depends from where it everywhere is. But, in common cases, if you declare variables in first frame of you timeline at top level of project you could get them using `root` keyword.
So your calls will be like

```
textField.text=root.e01_h;
```

Comment: nice answer but no style declaration for variable assignation

Comment: Actually I already tried that. It does not work either. It seems that the XML-function works, but the variables are always empty after the XML-part is done.

Is there a more easy way to load input from an XML to a variable?!

Comment: @Kodiak indeed. just copy/paste madness. fixed

Comment: Sure :-) The XML-Path in my example was just for demonstartion. Here ist the original XML-File-Code. (Sorry, I can only answer within comments for the first 8 hours here...)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<main>
 <experimente>
  <task>Waehle ein Experiment aus</task>
  <exp01>
   <header>Experiment 1: Der einfache Stromkreis</header>
   <description>Dieses Experiment veranschaulicht Dir wie der elektrische Strom fliesst</description>
  </exp01>  
 </experimente>
 <wissen>
  <text>Das ist der text</text>
 </wissen>
</main>

Comment: The XML-Code works in an easy example. But it is essential, that this procedure happens only at the beginning and the results can be used during the whole flash-code.

Comment: you call a node "e01" but it doesn't exist in your XML. Same for head/header and txt/description.

Comment: It was only for demsonstration. I just changed my original question and added the xml code.

Comment: What the point in such demonstration? Another xml structure will require another parsing code? Whatever it was, maybe you problem not in parsing procedure but in you understanding of "accessible over the whole flash-document". What code do you use to access this variables when you need them and where it code situatied.

Comment: I want to put the data of the xml on the beginning of the file in different variables. Somewhere in the flash document i just want to call the variables and put them into textboxes. For example: mytextbox.text = e01_h;

Comment: Does textboxes situated not on main timeline but inside other MovieClips?

Comment: Yes. They are. I have my Main-Action-Script over 50 frames on the top layer. Another Layer ist for example Frame 30-39 - where the textbox is located.

Comment: So your question now is not about XML anymore. It's about making global variables in AS 3.0 or about namespaces and reference system in flash project. For my personal opinion, you should avoid using global variables, because it pretty out of OOP consepts if AC3. So you must learn how to use references. I will add some code to my answer.

Comment: Ok. That's a new view. THANK YOU for the hint. I'll try that right now!